# How to open and block a view controller by specific dates

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk

I want to open and block a view controller in my iphone application using the local date on device.
For example I want that view to be available between the 1st of December untill the 31st of December 2012 and if the user tap on the button which is linked to that view before or after these dates he/she will have an alert view that tells them that view is not available.
 Basically something similar to local notification, is it possible to do something like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the button to call the following code with an IBAction:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd-MMM-yy";

NSDate *dec1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01-Dec-12"];
NSDate *jan1 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"01-Jan-13"];

NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

if( ([today compare:dec1] == NSOrderedDescending ) && ( [today compare:jan1] == NSOrderedAscending ) ) {
    // Go to View Controller
}
else {
    // Show AlertView
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great answer I will try later but do think that apple will approve the app that has that code.?

Comment: I can't say for sure (I really don't know what their criteria is when evaluating apps), but I'd be surprised if they had an issue with that.